# mysql if condition met then execute join otherwise not

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, yii

Hi I am stuck over a query. I want to execute join statement only when condition in if statement is true otherwise do not execute join and let the rest of query execute.

For example, my query is like this:

```
 SELECT `t`.`id`, `t`.`title`, `t`.`date_created`, `t`.`video_id`, `t`.`audio_id`, `t`.`created_by`, `t`.`updated`, `t`.`gamenumber`, `t`.`cat_id`, `t`.`is_deleted`, `t`.`marked_by`, `t`.`is_hidden`, `t`.`battle_type`, `t`.`media` FROM `postdata` `t`
```

if t.video_id != '' then run join statement

```
left join processes as pv on ( pv.video_id = t.video_id)
```

a common WHERE Statement in whole query

```
cat_id IS NOT NULL and is_deleted=0 and is_hidden=0 and battle_type="public" ORDER BY date_created
```

WHERE statement also requires this condition if t.video_id!='' then

```
pv.status=3
```

Basically if 'postdata' table contain field 'video_id' which contain id of videos. And 'processes' table contain these video_id as well. So if postdata.video_id is not empty then execute join statement to check if video_id is processes table contain status=3. (if status =3 only then fetch video records) otherwise if postdata.video_id is empty then execute the query without join statement and common Where Statement.

Please help.

Comment: why not just put `AND t.video_id <> ''` in the join predicate. you'll get null values for the rows that dont match.

Comment: How is this related to Yii?

Comment: @craafter, I have simplified the query in mysql. I am actually working on Yii and using CDbcriteria for executing this query.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use left join every time and add `pv.status=3` to join conditions, like:

```
<?php

$where = [
    'is_deleted'  => 0,
    'is_hidden'   => 0,
    'battle_type' => 'public',
];
$postdata = new postdataModel;
$processes = new processesModel;
$command = $postdata->getDbConnection()->createCommand()
    ->select('t.id, t.title, t.date_created, t.video_id, t.audio_id, t.created_by, t.updated, t.gamenumber, t.cat_id, t.is_deleted, t.marked_by, t.is_hidden, t.battle_type, t.media')
    ->from('postdata AS t')
    ->leftJoin('processes AS pv', 'pv.video_id = t.video_id AND pv.status = 3')
    ->where('cat_id IS NOT NULL AND is_deleted = :is_deleted AND is_hidden = :is_hidden AND battle_type = :battle_type')
    ->order('t.date_created DESC')
;
$data = $command->queryAll();
```

and mysql will resolve all for you...